# Is there a pythonic way execute some code when an instance goes out of scope?

Tags: python, scope

Coming from C++, I have been using constructor/destructors to perform RAII-like wrappers. So a local object that goes out of scope (e.g. end of a function) would have its destructor immediately called, which can be used to unlock a mutex, free a resource, or perform some deinitialization immediately.

Is there a pythonic way to do the same?

```
class DoSomethingWhenDone:
  def __init(self)__:
    pass

  def __out_of_scope__(self):
    # Do something!


def foo():
  obj = DoSomethingWhenDone()

  # Magic happens ...

  # <= Ensure __out_of_scope__() is called here
```

It seems `with file.open(...) as f:` is doing something like that?

Comment: Absolutely, thanks for flagging it

Comment: You don't need to put two underscores before and after every def statement in a class, you only need to use them while initialising the class (`def __init__(self)`). Also, put the `(self, parameters)` after the two underscores in `__init__`

Comment: Right, that was only to convey the idea that this could be a somewhat special method. Which is the case with `__enter__` and `__exit__`